# Text is not shown when hovering over in the navigation bar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am making a website, and in the navigation bar there is supposed to be another sub-navbar. I believe there is a logical error in CSS selector.

Here's my CSS code:

```
.trendinglist{    
    display: none;    
}

.dealerlist ul li #trending:hover .trendinglist{    
    display: block;    
    color: black;     
}
```

Comment: please add your both HTML and Css. Also if you provide us Jsfiddle or other cloud base text editor platform we can help you better and faster.

Comment: Could you please provide also some minimal HTML, just to reproduce the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Check the following example.

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
}

.navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333; 
}

.navbar a {
  float: left;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.subnav {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.subnav .subnavbtn {
  font-size: 16px;  
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0;
}

.navbar a:hover, .subnav:hover .subnavbtn {
  background-color: red;
}

.subnav-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  background-color: red;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}

.subnav-content a {
  float: left;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.subnav-content a:hover {
  background-color: #eee;
  color: black;
}

.subnav:hover .subnav-content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
  <a href="#home">Home</a>
  <div class="subnav">
    <button class="subnavbtn">About <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></button>
    <div class="subnav-content">
      <a href="#company">Company</a>
      <a href="#team">Team</a>
      <a href="#careers">Careers</a>
    </div>
  </div> 
  <div class="subnav">
    <button class="subnavbtn">Services <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></button>
    <div class="subnav-content">
      <a href="#bring">Bring</a>
      <a href="#deliver">Deliver</a>
      <a href="#package">Package</a>
      <a href="#express">Express</a>
    </div>
  </div> 
  <div class="subnav">
    <button class="subnavbtn">Partners <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></button>
    <div class="subnav-content">
      <a href="#link1">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#link2">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#link3">Link 3</a>
      <a href="#link4">Link 4</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
</div>
```